# CentOS6 - Display resolution

Tags: centos, centos6, resolution

I used the Display menu to change my resolution settings. Now I chose a setting too small by accident, but I can't revert because the screen is so small I can't click the append button to enlarge it.

Anyone know what I could do?

Answer (score 0):

Edit a relevant config file directly. You can go to a text console screen from X with Ctrl-Alt-(1 through 6). Can't specify the file to edit since you didn't name your GUI environment.